# Where should I drag and drop "label"?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Now I'm learning swift using Xcode, but I don't know where to drag and drop and why drag and drop "label" to  somewhere

should I drop no.1? or no.2? or no.3? and why I should drop there?

[image: see attached image]

Comment: Best Practices to declare IBOtlet after declaration of your class.

Answer (score 0):

If you drop it to 1, Xcode automatically generate an `@IBOutlet` for you. If you drop it to 2 or 3, then `@IBAction`. There's no other reason for that except that Xcode tries to be smart and help you organize code more nicely: properties with properties in the top of the class, methods – in the methods area. And you can also move declarations to another place later: except for code style matters, it doesn't matter, where exactly within your class you put declarations.

Answer (score 0):

as you are trying to take an IBOutlet for a label , its nice to keep it on top of the class (where you mention 1).

normally Xcode gives suggestion you , if you drug on top side it will be `@IBOutlet`
or you on bottom like 2 or 3 it will be `@IBAction` like you already took a button action in your code .

Your Solution On Code:

```
import UIKit
class CodePresentViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var YourLabel: UILabel! // insert @IBOutlet type property here 
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
    }
    @IBAction func tapBackButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        //Yout Button COde
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to own the label in your code, and then make some configuration to the label by code, use "1". It will give you a @IBOutlet label object in your code.
If you want to set the label's action, use "2" or "3".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).